# Console missing in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, console

My log window is missing in Xcode 4. I don't know what I did, but now there is just a blank gray box where it should be at the bottom the Xcode window.

How can I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode must have been in a funky state, closing and reopening fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

This button should do the trick:

[image]

... which, on my window, can be found here:

[image]